# How do I show the form in an MDI while loading data values asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have an MDI with a form that opens from one of the menu.

This form has a combo box that will be populated with values retrieved from a SQL Query.

At the moment, when I try to open the form up, there's a delay of a couple of seconds as the form will fire off the query to get the values back to populate the combo box.

Is there a way to have the form pop up and have the values populated later on?

I have an Event Handler on the Load for the form with the following:

```
private async void RerunForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      await this.LoadDataAsync();
}
```

where the LoadDataAsync() method will be as:

```
 private async void LoadDataAsync() {
        this._batchCollection = await repo.RetrieveBatchesAsync();
        this.lblLoading.Visible = false;


        this.cbBatchesToRun.DataSource = this._batchCollection;
        this.cbBatchesToRun.DisplayMember = "BatchNo";

        this.tbBatchCode.Text = this.repo.GetBatchStringValue(((Batch)this.cbBatchesToRun.SelectedValue).BatchNo);
}
```

RetrieveBatchesAsync() is defined as:

```
public async Task<List<Batch>> RetrieveBatchesAsync() {
    var batches = await (from b in this._context.Batches
                         orderby b.BatchNo descending
                         select b).ToListAsync();
    return batches;
}
```

For some reason, this is still all synchronous as the form takes a couple of seconds to open up compared to other forms that do not retrieve data.

What am I missing to allow the form to open up instantly and have it load data asynchronously? Essentially, what I am trying to do is to open up the form instantly with all the controls, and have it populate the control data afterwards and hide the "Loading" label that I have placed in the winform.

Edit: Added the Retrieve Batches Async Method

Comment: Are you sure `RetrieveBatchesAsync()` is actually asynchronous and not just pretending to be asynchronous?

Comment: @svick added the method definition into the question. I believe it shoudl be async as I'm using EF to retrieve this.

Comment: Is the UI thread actually blocked, i.e. does the application stop responding? If yes, could you pause the debugger while it's blocked and post the stack trace of the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

All is well.

It turns out the awaitable was working perfectly as I tested it by adding an

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

in the LoadDataAsync() method.

It just happened that the form was loading slower compared to other forms due to the amount of controls that I have in my form. (I believe).

Thanks for the breakpoint ideas.